# IBM Worklight steps for Facebook integration?

Tags: facebook, ibm-mobilefirst

I am new to Worklight ,i want Facebook integration in my application i did follow this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.1 but when i run the application nothing is shown on the screen ,any help ?
This is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Social Media App</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-      scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
      <!--
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
            <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png"> 
        -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
<script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
</head>

<body style="display: none;">

<!--        Setup the Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '721457581245356',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.1'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "js/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  </script>

  <!--application UI goes here-->
      Facebook Page

  <div class="fb-like" 
     data-share="true" 
     data-width="450"
     data-show-faces="true"></div>

  <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
  <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Help with what? Where is your code? Provide your Worklight project.

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser console (e.g. F12 in Chrome) if you open your WL app in the Mobile Browser Simulator?

Comment: @SwatiDevlekar, you should write this as an answer for others to benefit.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the Solution...
Just delete this line...

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

and the remaining code as it is ...
and its works all good :)

Answer (score 0):

For basic Facebook integration follow this steps:

1. Go to **Facebook Developers Site** - - **Apps** -- Your App Name (look for your app in the Apps tab).
2. Click on you **Apps** (now you are on your application dashboard).
3. Click the tab **Getting Started** towards your right side .
4. **Select a platform** to get started.
5. Here you will find steps for basic Facebook integration ,copy paste the code in your application as it is , just follow the instruction and your all set .

   hope this is helpful .